# Cannot import Silhouette Visualizer - tried almost everything

Tags: error-handling, silhouette, yellowbrick

I am trying to import Silhouette Visualizer and always get some errors, I have already updated the version of python and pip and tried uninstalling and installing scikit-learn and nothing works. I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the code, that will be very helpful :)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for checking out Yellowbrick!

This problem is occurring because scikit-learn recently [changed their public/private API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.22.html#id14), so `utils.safe_indexing` is now called `utils._safe_indexing`. In order for the utility to work in Yellowbrick, we [are working on a change](https://github.com/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick/pull/1138) to our usage of `safe_indexing` to support users with versions of scikit-learn >= 0.24 without deprecating support for users with versions of scikit-learn < 0.24.  That change will be available in the next version of Yellowbrick; you can track progress on the issue [here](https://github.com/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick/issues/1137).

In the meantime, you can avoid the error by downgrading your version of scikit-learn to <0.24 (e.g. `pip install scikit-learn==0.23`)!